# Why is rsync so slow?

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to backup a folder of 60G between my laptop and an external USB drive. Only 4G of data have been added. It took a long time to finish : 2 hours.

Here is the command :

```
rsync -av --exclude=target/ --exclude=".git/" --delete --link-dest=$destdir/backup.1 $element $destdir/backup.0
```

Do you have an explanation ?
What slows down rsync more : a lot of small files or big binary files (photos) ?

Answer (score 2):

As I don't exactly know your system, I am making a few assumptions here. If they don't match your situation, please clarify your question and I'll happily update my answer.

I am assuming you have a lot of files, no matter their sizes in the location you are copying from. This will cause a rather slow rsync caused by the design of the rsync protocol.

rsync works like this:

```
1. Build a file-list of the source location.

2. For all files in the source location:

  a. Get the size and the mtime (modification timestamp)
  b. Compare it with the size and mtime of the copy in the destination location
  c. If they differ, copy the file from the source to the destination

Done.
```

If you just have a few files, this will obviously be faster than for many files. Your usb drive might be your bottleneck, as retrieval of the size and timestamp will create a lot of jumps in the inode table.

Maybe a tool like iotop (in the case your on Linux, similar tools are available for almost all platforms) can help you identify the bottleneck.

The `--delete` option can also cause a slow rsync, if retrieving the complete file-list of the target location is slow (which is probable for an external, rotating USB disk). To verify that this is the problem, on any os with a bash, just type `time ls -Ral <target-location> > filelist.txt` (diverting the output to a file since putting out data on the screen is way slower). If this takes a lot longer than for your source disk, your target disk could be the bottleneck.